# What is going on with this program?

Tags: c++

When i write this line: cout<< "LOOK AT HERE PLEASE"; at the function 'insert' the program gives me this output: 1 0 but when erase the  line the program gives me this output: 1 2. 
Why this is  happening?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void initNode(struct Node *head, int n){
    head->data = n;
    head->next = NULL;
}

void insert(struct Node *head,int n){
    Node no; 
    Node *novo = &no;
    novo->data = n;
    novo->next = NULL;

    Node *cur = head;
    while(cur){
        if(cur->next == NULL){
            cur->next = novo;
            return;
        }
        cout<< "LOOK AT HERE PLEASE";
        cur = cur->next;

    }
}

void display(struct Node *head){
    Node *list = head;

    while(list){
        cout<<list->data<< " "<<endl;
        list = list->next;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}

int main(){
    Node head;
    initNode(&head,1);
    insert(&head,2);

    display(&head);



}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger and step through your code to see what is happening.

Comment: You might not want to pass back pointers to things you allocate on the stack.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Node no; 
Node *novo = &no;
```

To

```
Node *novo = new Node;
```

Stuff on the stack have short lives.

You then need to figure out how to prevent memory leaks (`delete` it somewhere!)

Answer (score 1):

What you did in the following code

```
void insert(struct Node *head,int n){
    Node no; 
    Node *novo = &no;
    ...

    Node *cur = head;
    while(cur){
        if(cur->next == NULL){
            cur->next = novo;
            return;
        }
```

is return a pointer to a local variable, which is undefined behavior.

You can fix it, as already pointed out by @ed-heal, by

```
Node *novo = new Node;
```

which will allocate a `Node` dynamically.

Comment: You get a +1 for acknowledging my answer